# How to create reference type in Swift?

Tags: swift

Here is a linkedlist problem:

input: `2 -> 4 -> 3` and `5 -> 6 -> 4`

expected `708`

because `342 + 465 = 708`

What confused me is:

`result = result!.next` in function `toList()`

result.next is a class, a reference type, but when I set it to result, it works like a rvalue, and `result` get the value type `nil`. Why and how could I fix it?

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     public var val: Int
 *     public var next: ListNode?
 *     public init(_ val: Int) {
 *         self.val = val
 *         self.next = nil
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    func toInt(_ l: ListNode?) -> Int {
        var power = 1, result = 0, curr = l
        while curr != nil {
            result += power * curr!.val
            curr = curr!.next
            power *= 10
        }
        // print("\(result)")
        return result
    }
    func toList(_ i: Int) -> ListNode? {
        var result: ListNode? = nil, num = i
        while num != 0 {
            result = ListNode(num % 10)
            result = result!.next
            num /= 10
        }
        return result
    }
    func addTwoNumbers(_ l1: ListNode?, _ l2: ListNode?) -> ListNode? {
        return toList(toInt(l1) + toInt(l2))
    }
}
```

Comment: You just assign a newly created `ListNode(num % 10)` to `result`, which obviously does not have any `next`. Of course `result.next` is `nil`.

Comment: And result is of type `ListNode?` ... therefore no problem with that !

Comment: result!.next always set to nil !!

Comment: Oh, that's a stupid mistake, sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: @HeyMIKU We all make silly mistakes. This first StackOverflow post of yours is great though; it's a real question with code you've tried. Welcome!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
func toList(_ i: Int) -> ListNode? {
        var result: ListNode? = ListNode(i % 10), num = i / 10
        while num != 0 {
            let nextResult = ListNode(num % 10)
            result!.next = nextResult
            result = result!.next
            num /= 10
        }
        return result
    }
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this Q&A) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting some code only.